# Calculating a negative number arithmetic expression through the stack

Tags: java, math, stack, operator-keyword

I need your help, to calculate negative numbers.
I could not consider negative numbers.
I'm unable to calculate only positive numbers.
I would be glad if you help me fix it.

I want to be sure - the complexity of the code is O(n)?

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class Q2_M3 // O(N)
{
    public static double Calculate(String st) 
    {
        char[] Arr = st.toCharArray();  
        Stack<Double> values = new Stack<Double>();// Stack for numbers: 
        Stack<Character> oper = new Stack<Character>();// Stack for Operators:

    for (int i = 0; i < Arr.length; i++)
    {
        if (Arr[i] >= '0' && Arr[i] <= '9')
        {
            StringBuffer sbuf = new StringBuffer();
            while ((i < Arr.length) && ((Arr[i] >= '0' && Arr[i] <= '9' )||(Arr[i] == '.')||(Arr[i] == '-')))
                sbuf.append(Arr[i++]);
            values.push( Double.parseDouble(sbuf.toString()));
            i--;
        }
        // Current token is an opening brace, push it to 'oper'
        else if (Arr[i] == '(')
            oper.push(Arr[i]);

        // Closing brace encountered, solve entire brace
        else if (Arr[i] == ')')
        {
            while (oper.peek() != '(')
              values.push(doArithmetic(oper.pop(), values.pop(), values.pop()));
            oper.pop();
        }

        // Current token is an operator.
        else if (Arr[i] == '+' || Arr[i] == '-' ||
                 Arr[i] == '*' || Arr[i] == '/')
        {
            // While top of 'oper' has same or greater precedence to current
            // token, which is an operator. Apply operator on top of 'oper'
            // to top two elements in values stack
            while (!oper.empty() && hasPrecedence(Arr[i], oper.peek()))
              values.push(doArithmetic(oper.pop(), values.pop(), values.pop()));
            oper.push(Arr[i]);
        }
    }
    // Entire expression has been parsed at this point, apply remaining
    // oper to remaining values
    double val= 0;
    while (!oper.empty()){
        if(!values.isEmpty())
        //values.push(doArithmetic(oper.pop(), values.pop(), values.pop()));
        values.push(doArithmetic(oper.pop(), values.pop(), values.pop()));
        val=values.peek();
    }
    // Top of 'values' contains result, return it
    return val;
}

// Returns true if 'op2' has higher or same precedence as 'op1',
// otherwise returns false.
public static boolean hasPrecedence(char op1, char op2)
{
    if (op1 == '(' || op2 == '(' )
        return false;
    if ((op1 == '*' || op1 == '/') && (op2 == '+' || op2 == '-'))
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

public static double doArithmetic(char oper, Double x, Double y)
{
    switch (oper)
    {
    case '+':
        return y + x;
    case '-':
        return y - x;
    case '*':
        return y * x;
    case '/':
        if (x == 0)
            System.out.println("Cannot divide by zero!");
        else
        return y / x;
    }
    return 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String st = "-5*(6+2)-12/4";
    String st2 = "20.2*(6.56567+2)-162/2";
    System.out.println(Calculate(st));
    System.out.println("Ans: "+Calculate(st2) );

}
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but your code does not follow Java identifier style conventions that are designed to make code readable.  Please fix this before you ask other people to read your code.

Comment: I don't see that many style conventions problem. It is quiet good for first question. I up vote it

Comment: If it were not for the while loops checking precedence then the complexity would be O(n). However, you can consider a case when the current operator needs to be compared with every operator on the operator stack. This makes the complexity somewhat higher. I would not worry about this as you need some really long strings for it to matter.

Comment: The Dijkstra Shunting-yard algorithm, of which this is a slightly mangled form, is known to be *O(N)*. @Salixalba

Answer (score 1):

So really you need to distinguish between a binary operator `a-b` and an unary operator `-c`.

In terms of a formal grammar, you can define an Expression something like with a Prefix being a number or - followed by a number

```
Expression :
    PrefixExpression
    Expression BinaryOp Expression
Prefix:
    NumberOrVar
    - NumberOrVar
    ( Expression )
NumberOrVar:
    0-9
    a-z
```

In code it becomes like

```
Expression() {
  while(more tokens) {
    Prefix();
    Char op = next input item, will be an operator
    PushOperator(op)
    Prefix()
  }

}

Prefix() {
    Char c = next input
    if(c == '-') {
          PushOperator(UnitaryMinus)
          c = next input
    }
    if(c in 0-9 )
          values.push(c)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly

```java
while ((i < Arr.length) && ((Arr[i] >= '0' && Arr[i] <= '9' )||(Arr[i] == '.')||(Arr[i] == '-')))
```

only makes since your condition looked like this

```java
if ((Arr[i] >= '0' && Arr[i] <= '9') || Arr[i] == '-')
```

The only thing changed is the stuff to the right.

I also changed the beginning of function to replace anywhere there is `-` sign to `+-` except at beginning.

```java
import java.util.*;
public class f {
    public static double Calculate(String st) {
        String pattern = "-";
        if (st.charAt(0)=='-')
            st = '-'+st.substring(1).replaceAll(pattern, "+-");
        else
            st = st.replaceAll(pattern, "+-");

        char[] Arr = st.toCharArray();
        Stack<Double> values = new Stack<>();// Stack for numbers:
        Stack<Character> oper = new Stack<>();// Stack for Operators:

        for (int i = 0; i < Arr.length; i++) {
            if ((Arr[i] >= '0' && Arr[i] <= '9') || Arr[i] == '-') {
                StringBuffer sbuf = new StringBuffer();
                while ((i < Arr.length) && ((Arr[i] >= '0' && Arr[i] <= '9' )||(Arr[i] == '.')||(Arr[i] == '-')))
                    sbuf.append(Arr[i++]);
                values.push( Double.parseDouble(sbuf.toString()));
                i--;
            }
            // Current token is an opening brace, push it to 'oper'
            else if (Arr[i] == '(')
                oper.push(Arr[i]);

            // Closing brace encountered, solve entire brace
            else if (Arr[i] == ')') {
                while (oper.peek() != '(')
                    values.push(doArithmetic(oper.pop(), values.pop(), values.pop()));
                oper.pop();
            }

            // Current token is an operator.
            else if (Arr[i] == '+' || Arr[i] == '-' || Arr[i] == '*' || Arr[i] == '/') {
                // While top of 'oper' has same or greater precedence to current
                // token, which is an operator. Apply operator on top of 'oper'
                // to top two elements in values stack
                while (!oper.empty() && hasPrecedence(Arr[i], oper.peek()))
                    values.push(doArithmetic(oper.pop(), values.pop(), values.pop()));
                oper.push(Arr[i]);
            }
        }
        // Entire expression has been parsed at this point, apply remaining
        // oper to remaining values
        double val= 0;
        while (!oper.empty()){
            if(!values.isEmpty())
                //values.push(doArithmetic(oper.pop(), values.pop(), values.pop()));
                values.push(doArithmetic(oper.pop(), values.pop(), values.pop()));
            val=values.peek();
        }
        // Top of 'values' contains result, return it
        return val;
    }

    // Returns true if 'op2' has higher or same precedence as 'op1',
    // otherwise returns false.
    public static boolean hasPrecedence(char op1, char op2) {
        if (op1 == '(' || op2 == '(' )
            return false;
        if ((op1 == '*' || op1 == '/') && (op2 == '+' || op2 == '-'))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public static double doArithmetic(char oper, Double x, Double y) {
        switch (oper) {
            case '+':
                return y + x;
            case '-':
                return y - x;
            case '*':
                return y * x;
            case '/':
                if (x == 0)
                    System.out.println("Cannot divide by zero!");
                else
                    return y / x;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String st = "-5*(6+2)-12/4";
        String st2 = "20.2*(6.56567+2)-162/2";
        System.out.println(Calculate(st));
        System.out.println("Ans: "+Calculate(st2) );
    }
}
```

Not sure if this makes things too slow, but it seems to work for the test cases in main method.

Comment: I don't like the manipulation of the input string to make it work. A good parser should be able to process this as is rather than introduce a hack at such an early stage.